# Project Namespace over all modules on Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am building ZF2 Application. I am thinking of doing my all modules under a Project namespace. Example:

```
ProjectName\ModuleName\Model\ModelName
ProjectName\ModuleName\Controller\ControllerName
ProjectName\ModuleName\Form\FormName
etc...
```

If it is possible in ZF2 or I am thinking something which is not possible until some big hack?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, such think I possible. It is called [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) and is supported by ZF2 through [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/).
Here is a simple `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "projectname/modulename",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "ProjectName\ModuleName": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, However I did not know how to use composer.json. I am assuming path for composer.json will be module/[ModuleName]/composer.json. Also make changes in application.config.php according to superdweebie, But it is not working either. Did I need somthing more to register composer.json under my module.

Comment: `composer.json` will not be registered. You should run `php composer.php install` to retrieve your application dependencies and generate the autoloader.

Comment: Now i added a parent Folder named [ProjectName] in module and copied my modules into that. then i make a composer.json under Module/ProjectName/ModuleName having code. After running "php ../../../composer.phar update" at Module/ProjectName/ModuleName.  But getting error 'invalid controller class or alias'

Comment: My json compose code is like 
`code` {
    "name": "ProjectName/ModuleName",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "ProjectName\\ModuleName": "src/"
        }
    }
} `code`
( I forced to use \\ instead of \ due to error.)

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible and simple. I do it myself.

In your `application.config.php` register your modules like this:

```
'modules' => array(
    'ProjectName\MyModule'        
),
```

Then in your module, have a PSR-0 directory structure, as indicated by @Florent. For further simplicity, the composer autoloader is really nice.